# How to Invoke Gatling successfulRequests Assert for All Feature File Requests

Tags: karate

For my performance test, an insignificant number of requests are failing the feature file assert for not having associated data needed for a subsequent request.  In my scala file I have:

```
global.successfulRequests.percent.is(99)
```

But it seems the feature file assert is still requiring 100% success:

```
> classpath:tests/sites/get_sites.feature:15 match $.data == '#[     58 (100.0%) _ > 0]'
```

The failing feature assert is:

```
And match $.data == '#[_ > 0]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by changing my global assert to:

```
global.successfulRequests.percent.gt(99)
```

Although, still not sure why I got that console output in Jenkins..